# Exception HRESULT: 0x800A03EC when inserting an Excel formula

Tags: c#, excel, vba

This is the exception I'm getting:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception
> from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
>
> at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName,
> BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData&
> msgData)
> at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set_Formula(Object
> value)

My code looks like this:

```
Range rng = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1");
rng.Formula = "=SUM(A4*C4;A5*C5;A6*C6;A7*C7)/SUM(A4:A7)";
```

Whenever I run this code I get the previously mentioned exception. However, when I run this code:

```
Range rng = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1");
rng.Formula = "=SUM(A4:A7)/4"
```

This works perfectly. No exception.

I've checked both formulas, they work perfectly fine in my Excel. I've tried setting:

```
Application.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic;
```

This does not help at all, I've been googling this solution and have not found anything useful. Does anyone have a clue what might be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right sign? `;` instead of `:`? Just a guess.

Comment: Yeah, using the correct sign, I must've checked 10 times.. It also works in an actual Excel worksheet, so there isn't a formula issue..

Comment: This is an array formula, and should have { } around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Excel's COM interface speaks American so you need to use the US list separators in the formula strings. replace your semicolons with commas and you should be fine.

```
Range rng = activeWorksheet.get_Range("A1");
rng.FormulaArray = "=SUM(A4*C4,A5*C5,A6*C6,A7*C7)/SUM(A4:A7)";
```

Comment: When interfacing with Excel this is a must-read: http://www.oaltd.co.uk/ExcelProgRef/Ch22/ProgRefCh22.htm

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your formula to an array formula using the FormulaArray property of the range object, using { } and an R1C1 reference.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104.aspx

> "=SUM(R4C1*R4C3;R5C1*R5C3;R6C1*R6C3;R7C1*R7C3)/SUM(R4C1:R7C1)"

Comment: Ok, now this does get inserted into the worksheet, however, this does not get calculated by Excel, it's treated as a string? I've tried `rng.FormulaArray = "{=SUM(A4*C4;A5*C5;A6*C6;A7*C7)/SUM(A4:A7)}"; `but it does not calculate anything.

Comment: Well that was on me, you have to use R1C1 for the FormulaArray property. Updating my answer.

Comment: Actually, just try removing the {} and use the formulaarray property

Comment: Just tried this: `rng.FormulaArray = "{=SUM(R4C1*R4C3;R5C1*R5C3;R6C1*R6C3;R7C1*R7C3)/SUM(R4C1:R7C1)}";` this does not calculate anything and inserts the actual string into the cell.. I've enabled R1C1 in my excel..

Comment: Yea, so no need for R1C1 reference, the documentation on MSDN is wrong, I'm updating on github no