# Excel IF statement results in error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, hresult

I am creating an excel report in C#. When I add a formula like below, everything works fine:

```
totalCellFormulaRange.Formula = "=SUM(AH7:AS7)"; //totalCellFormulaRange is a Range object from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

But now when I try to add a formula consisting of an if statement like below,

```
memberGuidesCellFormaulaRange.Formula = "=IF(LEFT(D7;12)=\"Welcome Pack\";O7*$AQ$4;0)";
```

then I get this error:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

The above if statement works 100% if typed out in a Excel sheet. It only fails in C# and the exception is thrown right when it hits this line of code.

Comment: You appear to be using semi colons in your IF not commas

Comment: @BugFinder regional settings force some of us to do that, when the comma is your decimal separator.

Comment: @BugFinder The Excel syntax for it statement on my side is "=IF(logical_test;value_if_true;value_if_false)"

Comment: is it any better with using @"=IF(LEFT(D7;12)=""Welcome Pack"";O7*$AQ$4;0)"  - failing that are you doing a lot of excel setting at one time?

Comment: try with the excel app Calculation set to manal

Comment: @BugFinder You were actually correct. When I tried it with the comma it worked :)

Comment: aye ... shocker :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although localization for excel allows for ";" use in place of commas, the COM interface doesn't register the ";" and a comma should be used instead.

```
memberGuidesCellFormaulaRange.Formula = "=IF(LEFT(D7,12)=\"Welcome Pack\",O7*$AQ$4,0)";
```

For more information about localization problems, and some general pointers when writing interop code for Excel, [see this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34879223/exception-hresult-0x800a03ec-when-inserting-an-excel-formula).

Comment: I removed the semi-colons and used the commas instead and it works now